# Android NSD: registerService returns Port 0 and Host null

Tags: java, android, networking, service, nsd

I'm trying to connect two Android devices via Network Service Discovery API (NSD) in a network. I followed the official Android webpage during implementation. One of the devices acts as the server and the other acts as the client. I ask the network for the next free port. But as soon as I register the Server in the network via registerService(nsdsInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener) the parameters in nsdsInfo are empty. So before calling this line of code nsdsInfo object contains a correct port and a correct host etc. After calling this method the Callback method in the listener onServiceRegistered() contains Port = 0 and Host = null.

Are there any guesses why the port and hostname is lost during registration process but the registrtation nevertheless successful?
On the other side, the other device cannot discover the server, even if the registration callback "onServiceRegistrered()" is fired.

Thanks in advance guys!

```
//Const
    private static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_speech._tcp";
    private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "speech";

    public WiFiServiceRegistry(Context ctx) throws IOException {

        this.context = ctx;

        initializeSocketAndPort();
        initializeNsdService();
        initializeRegistrationListener();

        if (nsdManager == null)
            nsdManager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
        System.out.println("nsdsinfo host" + nsdsInfo.getServiceName());
        System.out.println("nsdsinfo port" + nsdsInfo.getPort());
        nsdManager.registerService(nsdsInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the NsdServiceInfo.
     */
    private void initializeNsdService(){
        nsdsInfo = new NsdServiceInfo();
        nsdsInfo.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME);
        nsdsInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);
        nsdsInfo.setPort(mLocalPort);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the socket and port. Parameter 0 means that the next available port is used (dynamic).
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void initializeSocketAndPort() throws IOException {
        mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
        mLocalPort = mServerSocket.getLocalPort();
    }

    /**
     * Inizializes the registrationListener. Keeps track of the registration status.
     */
    private void initializeRegistrationListener(){
        mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
                System.out.println("WiFiServiceRegistry: Registration failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
                System.out.println("WiFiServiceRegistry: Unregistration failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
                System.out.println("WiFiServiceRegistry: Registered service");
                System.out.println("WiFiServiceRegistry: Port " + serviceInfo.getPort());
                System.out.println("WiFiServiceRegistry: Host " + serviceInfo.getHost());
                System.out.println("WiFiServiceRegistry: ServiceName " + serviceInfo.getServiceName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
                System.out.println("WiFiServiceRegistry: Unregistered service");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Solved: The problem was that NSD is based on Multicast Traffic. The network I was logged in didnt't support Multitraffic due to Security issues.. :)

Comment: I have the same behavior, but didn't find the cause. Interestingly, if I put IP and port into the service name, then I can transmit that information to the other device and successfully open the socket. Odd.